# 48 hour countdown that refreshes for new visitors only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm using this JQuery countdown script (http://reflejo.github.io/jquery-countdown/).

My question is, how can I make the 24-hour countdown refresh/resets for every new visitor **ONLY** while continue counting down with the remaining time left for returning visitors ?

Comment: What do you mean *"every new visitor ONLY"* ? You're using jQuery. jquery = client side.  You don't have to worry about other users. If you set something via a cookie or localstorage it will be *local* that user alone. If it exists  - returning user, else new user.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set a cookie on the visitors PC, containing the initial Date.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var countdownTime= getCookie("countdownTime");
    if (countdownTime == "") {
        countdownTime = new Date();
        if (countdownTime != "" && countdownTime != null) {
            setCookie("countdownTime", countdownTime, 365);
        }
    }
}    
$('#counter').countdown({
    endTime: countDownTime
});
```

Sort of this..

Comment: How's that code should look like?

Comment: just to clearify: User 1 visits your site -> Coundown is set with a value of 48 ours?, User 1 visits again: Same countdown continues?

Comment: That's right. But resets and starts again at 48 hours if new visitor.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't figure out how to lay this out properly on a page. Can you have this on Fiddle?